# ImportError: cannot import name signals when importing wsgi file in Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, django-wsgi

I'm getting the following error trying to run Django using apache:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=3294): Target WSGI script '/www/cocurate2_dev/startup.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=3294): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/www/cocurate2_dev/startup.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/cocurate2_dev/startup.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/www/cocurate2_dev/components/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
  File "/www/cocurate2_dev/components/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django import http
  File "/www/cocurate2_dev/components/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.http.response import (
  File "/www/cocurate2_dev/components/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
  File "/www/cocurate2_dev/components/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist
  File "/www/cocurate2_dev/components/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/www/cocurate2_dev/components/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models import signals  # NOQA
ImportError: cannot import name signals
```

Everything works find when using manage.py runserver. I've updated the wsgi file to be the same as the default one from django 1.10.
I've checked that signals.py exists inside django, I've also cleaned .pyc files.

Comment: See if this helps! http://serverfault.com/questions/817729/django-1-10-3-apache-wsgi-importerror-cannot-import-name-signals/817783

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but I'm not seeing any error about unreadable files in the log.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there actually was a file missing from the django installation for various reasons, it just wasn't signals.py but rather something it imported.
You can debug problems like this by running python with -v or -vv switch to make output verbose. I was able to see that it was trying to import another file from signals.py.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when my Django 1.10 install was *downgraded* to Django 1.6 by a third party.
After removing it and re-installing the correct version of Django, everything worked like a champ.